# How do I fix the xcrun unable to find simctl error?(flutter xcode error)

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos

Hi, I'm getting a critical error right now that is not being resolved.

I am currently working on a flutter project and for some reason my project which was working fine is not working when I debug it due to an xcode error.

I posted a picture of the error.

I think it's an SDK path error, because it keeps saying 14.2 version not found.
I've verified that I have 14.4 version and changed it to use that, but it still says it's building with 14.2 version. Has anyone else had the same issue as me?
Currently, the simulator is connecting properly.

[command line path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72RHh.png)

[sdk error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIVwK.png)

The error is shown below and the workaround I tried is shown below.

1. made sure the command line was reflected correctly in xcode.
2. updated mac os, xcode version
3. updated cocoa pod version
4. "sudo xcode-select -reset"
   "sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
   Tried.